# Pass input text value to function per click

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to insert the value inserted into an input in the database using Angular as the frontend and php as the backend but I'm not able to insert the input value into the method along with the user.id.

The input is for the reason of moderation when clicking on disapprove it is necessary to pass the reason but it is not entering.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { observerMixin } from '@rodrigowba/observer-component';
import { ResponseData, DefaultResponse } from '@rodrigowba/http-common';
import { BsModalRef, BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { ActionPayload } from '~/ngrx';
import {
  HotsiteUser,
  HotsiteUsersFacade,
  HotsiteUsersFormService,
  RegistrationStatusTypes,
  UpdateHotsiteUserRequest,
  HotsitePointsPrebase,
} from '~/admin/users';
import {
  updateHotsiteUser,
  hotsiteUserUpdated,
  hotsiteUserUpdateFailed,
  hotsiteUserRegistrationModerated,
  hotsiteUserModerateRegistrationFailed
} from '~/admin/users/state';
import { distinctUntilChanged, map, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './view.component.html',
})
export class ViewComponent extends observerMixin() implements OnInit {
  user$: Observable<HotsiteUser>;
  pointsPrebase$: Observable<HotsitePointsPrebase[]>;
  customFields$: Observable<{
    field: string,
    value: string
  }[]>;

  registrationStatusTypes = RegistrationStatusTypes;

  form: FormGroup;

  modalRef: BsModalRef;

  submiting = false;

  constructor(
    private hotsiteUsersFacade: HotsiteUsersFacade,
    private hotsiteUsersFormService: HotsiteUsersFormService,
    private modalService: BsModalService,
    private toastr: ToastrService
  ) {
    super();

    this.form = this.hotsiteUsersFormService.updateForm();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user$ = this.hotsiteUsersFacade.selectCurrentHotsiteUser();

    this.customFields$ = this.user$.pipe(
      map(user => Object.values(user.custom_fields)),
      map(customFields => customFields.map(customField => {
        let value = customField.value;

        if (Array.isArray(value)) {
          value = value.join(', ');
        }

        return {
          field: customField.field,
          value
        };
      }))
    );

    this.pointsPrebase$ = this.user$.pipe(
      map(user => user.id),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      tap(id => {
        this.hotsiteUsersFacade.fetchHotsitePointsPrebase(id);
      }),
      switchMap(id => this.hotsiteUsersFacade.selectHotsitePointsPrebaseByHotsiteUser(id))
    );

    this.observe(this.user$).subscribe(user => {
      this.form.patchValue(user);
    });

    this.observe(
      this.hotsiteUsersFacade.ofType(updateHotsiteUser)
    ).subscribe(() => {
      this.submiting = true;
    });

    this.observe(
      this.hotsiteUsersFacade.ofType<ActionPayload<ResponseData<HotsiteUser>>>(
        hotsiteUserUpdated,
        hotsiteUserRegistrationModerated
      )
    ).subscribe(action => {
      const { message, data } = action.payload;

      this.submiting = false;
      this.toastr.success(message);
    });

    this.observe(
      this.hotsiteUsersFacade.ofType<ActionPayload<DefaultResponse>>(
        hotsiteUserUpdateFailed,
        hotsiteUserModerateRegistrationFailed
      )
    ).subscribe(action => {
      const { message } = action.payload;

      this.submiting = false;
      this.toastr.error(message);
    });
  }

  onSubmit(id: string, data: UpdateHotsiteUserRequest) {
    this.hotsiteUsersFacade.updateHotsiteUser(id, data);
  }

  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>, size = 'modal-md') {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, { class: size });
  }

  approveRegistration(id: string,reason: string) {
    this.hotsiteUsersFacade.moderateRegistrationHotsiteUser(id, { approved: true,reason });
  }

  rejectRegistration(id: string,reason: string) {
    this.hotsiteUsersFacade.moderateRegistrationHotsiteUser(id, { approved: false,reason });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
 <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(user.id, form.value)" >
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(user.id, form.value)" >
        <div class="row mb-3">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Name</label>
              <input type="text" [value]="user.name" class="form-control" readonly />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>E-mail</label>
              <input type="text" [value]="user.email" class="form-control" readonly />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Document</label>
              <input type="text" [value]="user.document" class="form-control" readonly />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-12" *ngFor="let customField of customFields$ | async">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>{{ customField.field }}</label>
              <input type="text" [value]="customField.value" class="form-control" readonly />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="form-group">
              <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="admin" color="primary" ></mat-slide-toggle>
              <label class="ml-2">Admin</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="form-group">
              <mat-slide-toggle formControlName="active" color="primary" ></mat-slide-toggle>
              <label class="ml-2">Active</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ng-container *ngIf="pointsPrebase$ | async as pointsPrebase">
          <div class="row mb-3" *ngIf="pointsPrebase.length > 0">
            <div class="col-12">
              <h4 class="font-16 font-weight-bold">Points</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
              <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Chave</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Points</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let points of pointsPrebase">
                    <td>{{ points.value }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{ points.points }}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ng-container>
        <div class="form-row">
          <ng-container *ngIf="user.registration_status === registrationStatusTypes.AwaitingModeration">
            <div class="col-auto">
              <label>Reason</label>
              <input type="text" name="reason" placeholder="Reason of moderation..." class="form-control"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-success"
                (click)="approveRegistration(user.id,form.reason)"
              >
                <app-loading-label [loading]="submiting">Approved </app-loading-label>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-auto">
              <button
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-danger"
                (click)="rejectRegistration(user.id,form.reason)"
              >
                <app-loading-label [loading]="submiting">Repproved </app-loading-label>
              </button>
            </div>
          </ng-container>
          <div class="col text-right">
            <button
              type="submit"
              class="btn btn-orange"
              [disabled]="form.invalid || submiting"
            >
              <app-loading-label [loading]="submiting">Salvar</app-loading-label>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

> Error:
>
> Property 'reason' does not exist on type 'formGroup'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user776686 suggested, there is a formControlName missing linked to "reason" field.

To get the field value in HTML you should access to the FormGroup controls:

```
(click)="approveRegistration(user.id, form.controls.reason.value)"
```

Also you can create a "get" property in TS code and then access to it in HTML:

```
get reason() {
  return this.form.controls.reason.value;
}

(click)="approveRegistration(user.id, reason)"
```

BTW, a field can be accessed too through the "get" method of a FormGroup:

```
get reason() {
  return this.form.get('reason').value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It expects a control with the attribute `formControlName="reason"` which is not present here:

```
<input type="text" name="reason" placeholder="Reason of moderation..." class="form-control"/>
```

This might be a reason.

If that doesn't help, you my also want to look into the `*ngIf` condition here:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="user.registration_status === registrationStatusTypes.AwaitingModeration">
```